# copy row from asp.net gridview to new page using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to copy a row from a gridview to be displayed on a new page through a button in one of the columns in the gridview. I have my gridview populated from an Access database that is linked to my project. I have tried several different things, but nothing will display the row information when the project is ran. The current code I am trying from the actual dataview  is:

Example 1a

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" Width ="90%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Grid1_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="Title">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Console" HeaderText="Console" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year_Released" HeaderText="Year Released" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ESRB" HeaderText="ESRB Rating" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Score" HeaderText="Personal Score" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher" HeaderText="Publisher" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Developer" HeaderText="Developer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" HeaderText="Genre" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Purchase" HeaderText="Purchase Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="7%" ShowHeader="False">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" Text="View" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/ViewDetails.aspx?RowIndex=" & Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the codebehind code on the page where I am trying to have the code be displayed is:

Example 1b

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Me.Page.PreviousPage IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("RowIndex"))
            Dim GridView1 As GridView = DirectCast(Me.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Grid1"), GridView)
            Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)
            lblTitle.Text = row.Cells(0).Text
            lblConsole.Text = row.Cells(1).Text
            lblYear.Text = row.Cells(2).Text
            lblESRB.Text = row.Cells(3).Text
            lblScore.Text = row.Cells(4).Text
            lblPublisher.Text = row.Cells(5).Text
            lblDeveloper.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
            lblGenre.Text = row.Cells(7).Text
            lblPurchase.Text = row.Cells(8).Text

        End If
    End Sub
```

I have also tried another set of code where the button on the gridview was:

Example 2a

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLink" runat="server" Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Title", "~/ViewDetails.aspx?Id={0}") %>'/>
```

Where the codebehind code is:

Example 2b

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim GameTitle As String = Request.QueryString("Id")

            Dim connString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "DATA SOURCE=" + Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data" + "db1.accdb")
            Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connString)
                connection.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
                Dim command As New OleDbCommand((Convert.ToString("SELECT * from [Video_Games] WHERE Title='") & GameTitle) + "'", connection)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    lblTitle.Text = reader(0).ToString()
                    lblConsole.Text = reader(1).ToString()
                    lblYear.Text = reader(2).ToString()
                    lblESRB.Text = reader(3).ToString()
                    lblScore.Text = reader(4).ToString()
                    lblPublisher.Text = reader(5).ToString()
                    lblDeveloper.Text = reader(6).ToString()
                    lblGenre.Text = reader(7).ToString()
                    lblPurchase.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader(8).ToString()).ToShortDateString()
                End While
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried making variations of both, mainly the second, but whatever I try the labels are not populated with the row information. Any assistance would be appreciated, and I can post any other code needed, like how I populated the gridview. Thank you.

Comment: Is the 2nd example also an attempt to load the labels or is that for something else?

Comment: It is also attempt. The example 2a is the button from the original gridview and example 2b is the vb.net code from the page I want to code to appear on.

Comment: It ex2 is also an attempt, then why do you have `If Not Postback`? It will have to be a postback. Also are you sure you are getting a value and the correct value in `Request.QueryString("RowIndex")`?

Comment: I switched the postback, though it did not fix the problem. I am not sure if the Request string is acquiring a value. Do you know how I can check?

Comment: Yes use the debugger and see what the value is for `GameTitle`

Comment: GameTitle is not getting a value.when the code is ran.

Comment: Ok well that's the issue then. You need to fix that

Comment: I am assuming then the information is not being sent then? I have tried a few different PostBackUrl strings, and none seem the work. The button with the PostBackUrl that I am trying to use is:                         <asp:Button ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                            Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Title", "~/ViewDetails.aspx?Id={0}") %>'/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as changing the AutoEventWireup to "true" in my .aspx file.